# C++ OR condition not working properly

Tags: c++

I have a very weird problem right now which is my `||`-condition not working properly.
This is my code:

```
cout << "Please enter type: "; 
    cin.ignore();
    std::getline(std::cin, type);
    transform(type.begin(), type.end(), type.begin(),::toupper);
    cout << type << endl;
        if (type != "TYPE B" || type != "B"){   
            cout << "Please re-enter type: ";

            std::getline(std::cin, type);

            }
        }
```

When I input the value b or type b, it brought me into that loop which should not happen.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your about to realize `type != "TYPE B" || type != "B"` will *always* be true. It can never be *both* of those *simultaneously*.

Comment: omg thanks! cant believe i make this type of simple mistake..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will always be true and you'll be asked to re-enter the type.

You want `&&` instead of `||` - You want to re-enter the type if its not `"TYPE B"` *and* it also not `"B"`

Answer (score 1):

`type != "TYPE B" || type != "B"` expression is always true. No matter what's the `type`, it cannot be equal to two strings that are not equal to each other.

If the intention is to allow only `"B"` and `"TYPE B"` strings, use `&&`, like this

```
if (type != "TYPE B" && type != "B")
```

or negate the results of the `OR`, like this:

```
if (!(type == "TYPE B" || type == "B"))
```